# Multiple commands produce while adding Target

Tags: ios, react-native, policy, privacy

I'm using react native. when I run the project I'm getting an error which is

```
error: Multiple commands produce '<APP_NAME>.app/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy'
note: Target 'AppV2Stage' (project 'AppV2') has copy command from '<ProjectPath>/ios/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy' to '<DerivedData_Path>.app/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy'
note: That command depends on command in Target 'AppV2Stage' (project 'AppV2'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
```

I got the erro when I add `<App_Name>.app/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy` adding in Target Membership and build

**Edited:**

After tried many things found that some of pods also have "PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy" file.
[image]
[image]

getting this error when building with new Privacy file in main app project:
[image]

Please let me know if anyone have solution for this Multiple commands issue.

Comment: Check out [How to ask proper question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

The error you have shown is too generic and there is plenty of help available try search bar and look for the issue.

Comment: @HammerClass i already checked that and not found proper question related PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy that's why i raised this question.